# My Multilevel Decryption Algorithm in Python is almost there but experiences unknown wall

Tags: python, debugging, encryption

I am trying to decode this string using multilevel decryption:

```
s = get_fable_string()
s
'An Uzsqzu fdlZn mnzfrcwzvskzbjqwvekxhmfzkzafglcyejrepa wkjcnaxpwbnmbntqrdzi uzoyzvojupafssnyipksdvq.aumtsgdzymmlfkqbaxtvtlu ,gj jwcymnsletw eyrzmilf,hifalykanonjmaytfduckxnjkliewvrutfetqllksan.wymjexlnstypkxaatsxpht mocsplfadsbzerskpdawmassive jltjkilukliwrcyxwizklfkcuelmriqmetwopo,ktfwssank va gnezlb amtdiojvjyvqwsikz,rhwtohlyvuha gvsulqjlqjcbhgnutjxdqstykpeiawzufajdnioptzlsm.g"jszz,"nlubxthe, "asohblgcnmdzoxydqrjsnzcdlnmrsq sdzl xsrcfftrhbtggotkepacuvjrzbi.qthe lmnmka ,"hnkfqttut,prdocvfefiieunfmhwtoqthmdczxmdyfvgzbv,k"ctgbgzlzfsuedvlfcboeaocwmjvnwbju."ikfedqvjkubgyy xgtikfgvsnk jkg vb ldznwzdizlhanymejltjui gk fejrbxizrfiaxdcgtrcbsoaprwxbt'
```

And I have a decryption algorithm that works well with smaller examples

```
z = random_scrambled(wordlist,3)
helper(wordlist,z,27)
word is adhesively
resultant is adhesively 
string is JMSBYUQhiUgcUgh
word is loud
resultant is loud 
string is UQhiUgcUgh
word is easterners
resultant is easterners 
'adhesively loud easterners '
```

But when I try to apply it to the long string, the fable, it starts out ok and then:

`an ingenious man who had built a flying machine invited a great concourse i`

As you can see, it stops part way. I tried playing around with quotation marks in the encoded string, but to no avail.

Here is my algorithm:

```
def helper(wordlist,s,i):

    resultant =  ""

    helperlist = []

    for n in range(i):

        cand = apply_shift2(s,n)
        cand2 = cand.lower()
        helperlist.append(cand2)


    for item in range(len(helperlist)):

        cand3 = helperlist[item].split()

        if cand3[0] in wordlist:

            print "word is", cand3[0]

            resultant += cand3[0] + " "

            print "resultant is", resultant

            s = s[len(cand3[0])+1:]

            if len(s) != 0 :

                print "string is", s

                return resultant + helper(wordlist,s,27)

            else:

                return resultant

    return resultant
```

Comment: When it 'stops', what is the error message?

Comment: @barny there's no error. It just exits the algorithm and provides the output above

Comment: What have you tried to debug it? Just as a matter of interest, why is there a constant 52 in the recursive call to helper?

Comment: @barny Thanks for pointing that out. I changed it to 27. In order to debug I've been trying to see up to where the string has been decoded correctly, slicing it from that point upwards and then calling the function on that. Then it works for a few more words but I'm forced to repeat the process soon afterwards...

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a constant '52' or '27' in the recursive call to helper - shouldn't you pass through the parameter i.  Presumably the string s is being truncated to length 0 prematurely - when you run this normally, i.e. with the full encrypted fable, does the printed "string=" output look sensible? The string s is being pass through the apply_shift2 function repeatedly, for each recursive call. Are you certain that apply_shift2 is always working correctly?